# tensorflow c++ api memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, tensorflow

When i use tensorflow c++ api in my project, GraphDef memory does not release after session->close(). i find same questions in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5302
, but use LD_PRELOAD to load tcmalloc can't solve my problem.
**ENV Info**
CentOS 7
CPU only
tensorflow 1.0 and python 2.7.6
**Short code**

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    GraphDef graph_def;
    Status status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), "models/graph.pb", &graph_def);
    if (!status.ok()) {
        std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    // Initialize a tensorflow session
    Session* session;
    status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);
    if (!status.ok()) {
        std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "____Load graph success____!" << "\n";
    // Add the graph to the session
    status = session->Create(graph_def);
    if (!status.ok()) {
        std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    sleep(5);
    session->Close();
    cout << "----Close graph success----!" << "\n";
    sleep(5);
}
```

Running it and memory usage would increase。（proportional to graph file size）

Comment: See sample code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/public  `session` should be deleted.

Comment: I use session->close() in final of loop. it's some other method to release the resource? and i find when i move `GraphDef graph_def;`  `Status status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), "models/graph.pb", &graph_def);` out of the loop, the memory usage is down.

Comment: `delete session;`  see the sample I linked above - `session` is managed by `unique_ptr`

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, Memory is perfectly handled! Maybe i should see the sample code detail~